# Using path parameters in <view-id> with PrettyFaces

Tags: prettyfaces, pretty-urls

Many pages in a typical JSF applications are *dynamic*, meaning that there is a *template* view that would be used to render every object of a given type. For these pages PrettyFaces rewriting solution works great and effortless. An example is a web application that displays a product, basing on its id, or other unique field. There is typically one view related to such a display, say `product.xhtml`, and one view parameter, holding the unique field of a product, say `name`.

With a simple setting we get all requests like `/product.xhtml?name=exact-product-name` rewritten as, for example, `/products/exact-product-name`:

The URL mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="viewProduct">
    <pattern value="/products/#{ name : productBean.name }" />
    <view-id value="/store/product.xhtml" />
    <action> #{ productBean.loadData } </action>
</url-mapping>
```

The view:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="name" name="name" required="true" />
</f:metadata>
```

The model:

```
public class ProductBean implements Serializable {

    private ProductService productService;

    private String name;

    private Product product;

    public String loadData() {
        if(!((name == null) || (name.equals(""))) {
            Product product = productService.findByName(name);
            this.product = product;
            return null;
        }
        return "error";
    }

}
```

However, there are also many pages with *static* data, that are not *templated* in a way described above, using view parameters. These pages simply display what was put in them. For example, there may be many articles that were created as separate views (like `/pages/articles/article1.xhtml` and so on). Using PrettyFaces we would need to create as many URL mapping as the number of such pages. But, *in fact* this behavior can also be *templated* in one URL mapping. Unfortunately, this is not supported in current PrettyFaces release.

The proposed enhancement of the PrettyFaces framework is the following:

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleName }" />
    <view-id value="/store/#{ articleName }.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

or, using an `ArticleBean` (containing, for example, two fields: `articleName` and `articleId`, where name is defined in setter of id field as a unique value):

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleId : articleBean.articleId }" />
    <view-id value="/store/#{ articleBean.articleName }.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

or using other predefined dependence based on an EL-expression, which is in turn based on a unique correspondence.

I want to emphasize that this is not going to be a `DynaView` because there is no uncertainty in the view-id: there is a one-to-one correspondence between a `<pattern>` and a `<view-id>`.

What do you think about implementing this feature in PrettyFaces?

Comment: Reminds me one thing I've done earlier when creating my JSF-2 CMS, since I've done my custom URL rewriting (based on `Filter` and `ViewHandler`), I've kept an option that when URL comes with a `.*` at the end, I keep it static, ortherwise there is an internal redirect depending on the kind of data (Posts are in MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

I think Stackoverflow is not the right place to discuss proposals for PrettyFaces. You should have a look at the [PrettyFaces Support Forum](http://ocpsoft.org/support/) for that.

There are some options for you to implement something like this. IMHO you could try to do this view DynaView. Even if there is a one-to-one relationship between pattern and view-Id like your wrote. However dynaview has some problems especially with outbound rewriting.

But you should have a look at [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/), which is the successor of PrettyFaces. With Rewrite it is very simple to implement such a requirement:

```
.addRule(Join.path("/articles/{articleName}").to("/store/{articleName}.xhtml"))
```

Have a look at the [configuration examples](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/examples/) of Rewrite.

Comment: It was not meant to be a proposal in the first place. By this question and answer I wanted to share my findings on the issue I faced and show for possible workarounds in the current PrettyFaces release for potential readers. As for the usage of Rewrite, I didn't want to mix them both in one application.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the great job of keeping up the PrettyFaces project!

Answer (score 0):

As far as the setup of `pretty-config.xml` doesn’t currently support this feature, there are some workarounds to achieve this functionality. I will describe them below.

### A dummy view with `<f:event>` that handles navigation to the final pages based on a view parameter in a dummy bean.

URL mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleName : articleBean.articleName }" />
    <view-id value="/handle-article-redirection.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

View `handle-article-redirection.xhtml`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="articleName" name="articleName" required="true" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{articleBean.handleRedirect}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Model:

```
public class ArticleBean {

    private ArticleService articleService;

    private String articleName;

    private String articleUrl;

    public void handleRedirect() {
        if(!((articleName == null) || (articleName.equals(""))) {
            String url = articleName;
            //String url = articleService.getUrlForArticleName(articleName);
            //articleUrl = url;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/" + url + ".xhtml");
            return null;
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/home.xhtml");
    }

}
```

### A meaningful view with a dynamic `<ui:include>` that imports the necessary page content as a snippet, basing on the bean value / view parameter.

URL mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleName : articleBean.articleName }" />
    <view-id value="/article.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

View `article.xhtml`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="articleName" name="articleName" required="true" />
</f:metadata>
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:include src="/#{articleBean.articleUrl}.xhtml" />
</h:body>
```

Model:

```
public class ArticleBean {

    private ArticleService articleService;

    private String articleName;

    private String articleUrl;

    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
        if((!(articleName == null)) || (articleName.equals("")) {
            articleUrl = articleName;
            //articleUrl = articleService.getUrlForArticleName(articleName);
        } else {
             articleUrl = null;
        }
    }

}
```

### A `DynaView` URL mapping with a method that returns a proper outcome.

URL mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleName : articleBean.articleName }" />
    <view-id value="#{articleBean.getViewPath}" />
</url-mapping>
```

No extra view needed.

Model:

```
public class ArticleBean {

    private ArticleService articleService;

    private String articleName;

    private String articleUrl;

    public String getViewPath() {
        this.articleName = articleName;
        if(!((articleName == null) || (articleName.equals(""))) {
            articleUrl = articleName;
            //articleUrl = articleService.getUrlForArticleName(articleName);
            return articleUrl;
        }
        return "error";
    }

}
```

### A *template* view that loads the page data from the database, hence there will be no separate views for those pages.

URL mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="viewArticle">
    <pattern value="/articles/#{ articleName : articleBean.articleName }" />
    <view-id value="/article.xhtml" />
    <action> #{ articleBean.loadData } </action>
</url-mapping>
```

View `article.xhtml`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="articleName" name="articleName" required="true" />
</f:metadata>
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:panelGroup>
        #{articleBean.content}
    <h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
```

Model:

```
public class ArticleBean {

    private ArticleService articleService;

    private String articleName;

    private String articleUrl;

    private String content;

    public void loadData() {
        if(!((articleName == null) || (articleName.equals(""))) {
            articleUrl = articleName;
            //articleUrl = articleService.getUrlForArticleName(articleName);
            content = articleService.getContentForArticleName(articleName);
        } else {
             articleUrl = null;
             content = null;
        }
    }

}
```

### Write a custom `WebFilter` or a `NavigationHandler`.

What is the best alternative, well, it depends. All of them have their pros and cons.